# How can I invoice a US company being a foreign non resident in USA?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, non-resident, services

I'm a nonresident alien in US and I need to invoice a US company due to service.
The company can provide W8 or W9 forms to proceed with the payments, but I need to provide an invoice confirming that I'll be paying all income taxes.
Is this invoice "automatic" when I use this W8 form? If not, how can I provide this invoice?

Comment: I think you should ask that company to explain to you what it is that they want.

Answer (score 1):

You should ask the company you are working with what they require in an invoice. One thing is certain, invoicing will not simply be "*automatic*" because you file a W8 or W9.

At a minimum, your invoice should include your name (or company name), contact information, a break down of the goods / services provided & prices + taxes, a total amount, the date, payment terms (e.g.: *due on receipt, 2/15 net30, net 30*) and please... for the sake of their bookkeeping and yours... each invoice should have a unique identifier (*not the date*), even if it is something as simple as "Invoice#1".